# can you use a wild card for C_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: c, header, include

If I downloaded a source tree with a number of folders with source files in them can I use

```
c_include_path=/some/directory/*
```

so it searches through all the folders for the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible, you need to provide each directory path separately, most probably using `-I` option.

The usual convention is, however, to have a top level header at the directory root which includes other required headers with relative path, something like

*root.h*

```
#include <this/is/one.h>
#include <that/is/another/one.h>
```

and, we use `#include <root.h>` with `-I /path/to/rootdir`

Comment: You're welcome. :) You can also consider [accepting an answer that helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062), which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you. :)

Comment: @clawhammer1234 yep, basically. Though, let me make it clear, this is no mandate, click that tickmark ___only if___ you find the answer helpful. :)